# The function doesn't return the right thing

Tags: java

Everyone, there is a question that disturbs me a lot. I want to get a `StringBuffer` from a function as follows:

```
public static StringBuffer getString() throws IOException
{
    StringBuffer  sb=new  StringBuffer(" ");
    File file=new  File("d:\\c.txt");
    BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    String  s;
    do
    {
        s=br.readLine();
        if(s!=null){
            sb.append(s);
        }
    }while(s!=null);
    System.out.println(sb.length());
    return  sb;
}
```

But when in the `main()` function, I want to call the function, the code follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
    StringBuffer  sBuffer=getString();
    System.out.println(sBuffer);
}
```

It can print the length but it can't print the `StringBuffer` itself, it disturbs me a lot, anyone can help?

Comment: I,m sorry ,i  don't know  how  to  format  the  code  as   your  want ,i'm sorry

Comment: 100001   the  is  a  lot  of  letter  in  the  c.txt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is ok and it is working. I did 2 modifications when I tried to run it in eclipse.

1)File file=new  File("d:\c.txt");------->File file=new  File("c:\chinmay\c.txt");

2)Have to handle the exception while calling the function using try and catch

```
try{
```

Buffer = getString();} 
catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace();        }

And it is working..  I have attached the code and the output

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;


public class TestMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        StringBuffer sBuffer=null;
        try {
            sBuffer = getString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(sBuffer);

    }
    public static    StringBuffer  getString() throws IOException
    {   
     StringBuffer  sb=new  StringBuffer(" ");
     File file=new  File("c:\\chinmay\\c.txt");
     BufferedReader br= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
     String  s; 
     do 
      {
      s=br.readLine();
      if(s!=null){
                 sb.append(s);
                  }
    }while(s!=null);
     System.out.println(sb.length());
     return  sb;
    }

}
```

The file  c:\chinmay\c.txt  contains **Online Java Training**

and the output I got when i ran is

**21
Online Java Training**

Hope it helps!

Comment: yes  ,it  works  when  the c.txt has  few  letter  ,but  when  in  my  case,  c.txt  has  a  lot  of  letters, and  i  must  pick  some  letter  in  it ,but when the  c.txt  has    l  lot  of  letter  ,it din't work,have  any  solution  for  this  case

Comment: I just tried with 81 words and 767 char in c.txt. It worked. I copied the whole program code it self in to the c.txt. It worked.

Comment: yes,maybe  the  eclipse  problem,when   i  copy  the  code  file  in  other   place  ,it  runs  well ,when  i run   in  eclipse,it  fails  ,it's  the  eclipse   problem,thank  you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following and make sure you close "br":

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    StringBuffer  sBuffer=getString();
    System.out.println(sBuffer);

}
```

---

```
public static StringBuffer getString() throws IOException {
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    File file = new File("d:\\c.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    byte[] letter = new byte[1];

    String str = "";
    while (fis.read(letter) > 0) {          
        str = new String(letter);
        sb.append(str);
    }
    System.out.println(sb.length());

    return sb;
}
```

Comment: your  answer  dosen't work ,i  cna't  print the letter in  the StringBuffer

Comment: 1- I'm using a "StringBuilder". 2- Are you trying to output a LETTER or the whole content of the file?

Comment: i  want  to see  if  the  StringBuffer  can  receive  all  the  letter  in  c.txt,if it  can  ,there  will  someother   function  will can  the   StringBuffer ,sorry  to  disturb  you

Comment: LOOK at my modified code for the getString() above. Let me know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working without any issues. Check if the d:\c.txt is existing. If it exists, check the content. May be delete all and type fresh content and try again.

Comment: i,m sure  i  have  a  file named c.txt  in  my  D  Hard disk,and  the c.txt  file  also  have  letter  in  it ,also  when  i  debug  my  code ,i  found  the StringBuffer  have  received  the letter  in  the  c.txt,  but  i  can't  print  all  the  letter  even  one,help?

Comment: I tried your code. It is running and is giving me result without any change. what is your java configuration?

Comment: I  don't konw  ,would  you  tell me  how  to  get  the  java  configuration